# How to populate combobox with two elements from CultureInfo

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, .net-4.5

I need to build a function to populate a *Combobox* with 2 elements (EnglishName and CurrencyEnglishName) from CultureInfo. Reading other posts here, I found the code below, that populates the *Combobox* with one element using a list. How can I populate the *Combobox* with 2 elements using a code similar to this?

```
public static List<string> GetCountryList()
{
    List<string> cultureList = new List<string>();


    CultureInfo[] cultures =  CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);

    foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
    {
        RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo(culture.LCID);

        if (!(cultureList.Contains(region.EnglishName)))
        {
            cultureList.Add(region.EnglishName);                     
        }
    }

    return cultureList;
}
```

Additional information: Framework 4.5, Windows Form.

Comment: What framework do you use for this combobox?

Comment: I'm using framework 4.5.

Comment: Is this WPF, Windows forms, Xamarin, Unity? Please add more information to your question.

Comment: It is a Windows form in Visual Studio.

Comment: `cultureList.Add(region.EnglishName + "-" + region.CurrencyEnglishName);` did you try this ?

Comment: That would work, but I would need to split the string before populating the combobox. Instead, I'm looking for (if possible) a shorter way to add the EnglishName as a DisplayMember and the CurrencyEnglishName as a ValueMember in the combobox.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this, I have tested.
First define a custom class for binding:

```
public class CountryCurrencyPair
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}
```

Then simplify query by Linq:

```
    public List<CountryCurrencyPair> GetCountryList()
    {
        return CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
            .Select(c => new RegionInfo(c.LCID)).Distinct()
            .Select(r => new CountryCurrencyPair()
            {
                Country = r.EnglishName,
                Currency = r.CurrencyEnglishName
            }).ToList();
    }
```

At last bind to control:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<CountryCurrencyPair> lst = GetCountryList();
        this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Country";
        this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Currency";
        this.comboBox1.DataSource = lst;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Lei Yang! Your code worked perfectly. Regards,